# Opening a new activity from a button

Tags: android

I am new to development and I am trying to create a new activity (new page) on the click of a button. I am really stuck. Here is the code for my main activity but I cannot get rid of the error...

```
package com.example.android.buttons;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OnClickButtonListener();
}

public void OnClickButtonListener() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intentMain2Activity = new intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }

    );


}}
```

The error shows up on the startActivity(intent) line... The word intent has the red underline?? with a caption saying "cannot resolve symbol "intent"

Comment: Which error getting?

Comment: Inside your start activiy put intentMain2Activity instead of intent

Comment: Do it as `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);startActivity(intent);
`

Comment: I consider this question as **a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change intent to intentMain2Activity

```
 Intent intentMain2Activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
 startActivity(intentMain2Activity);
```

Comment: Also change  `new intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);` to `new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);`

Comment: Wow, such a simple correction :)

Comment: OK, So now when I run the app I am getting an error log and the phone displays a messge saying "unfortunately, buttons has stopped working. Buttons being the name of the app (i made a quick name for testing purposes)...

Comment: show your xml; in question

Comment: Here is the .XML for the Activity _main

Answer (score 1):

you can also write in one line as

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));
            }

        }

);
```

Comment: ohh !! yes . thanks @Sanoop

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

```
package com.example.android.buttons;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OnClickButtonListener();
}

public void OnClickButtonListener() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intentMain2Activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intentMain2Activity);
                }

            }

    );


}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intentMain2Activity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(intentMain2Activity);
```